# Dojo toolkit support for IOS8

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on a hybrid application using IBM worklight and Dojo toolkit. On IOS8, only the button clicks are working. Rest all the elements do not respond to any click. Has anyone tried using Dojo toolkit 1.9 with IOS8? Does this version of Dojo supports IOS8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported for Dojo 1.9.X. It was released more than a year ago and iOS8 is brand new:

[Release notes](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/1.9.html#releasenotes-1-9) state that iOS6 is supported

Even [Dojo 1.10](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/releasenotes/1.10.html#releasenotes-1-10) does not claim to support iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

iOS8 is not released, so it is difficult to claim iOS8 support ;) That said some problems have been found on the beta (in particular around scrolling) but be assured that Dojo 1.9 (and 1.10) will be updated to bring iOS8 support. So you will be able to run your app on iOS8.

PS: release notes are corresponding to initial releases i.e. 1.9.0 and are (unfortunately) not updated for dot release. Current 1.9.X release (1.9.3) does support iOS7.

Edit:
Since September 15, Dojo 1.8.7, 1.9.4 and 1.10.1 now support iOS8. See here www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21684538 on how to upgrade your IBM Worklight release.

Comment: Do you have a link or bug ticket for this to subscribe to... Most of the issues are am seeing so far is in the way touch events are being handled/ fixed( see dojo/on line 554 https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/on.js).. iOS 8 has deprecated the manipulation of these.

Comment: I have created a bug ticket for all ios8 issues here: https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18168

Comment: IOS 8 is being released Sept17 and dojo has checked in a fix a while back.  does anybody know when IBM will release the fix?

Comment: Indeed Dojo 1.8.7, 1.9.4 and 1.10.1 now support iOS8. See here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21684538 on how to upgrade your IBM Worklight release.